# How to backup DynamoDB using boto3.resource

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto3, database-backups

How I can modify following code using boto3.resource()

```
client = boto3.client('dynamodb', region_name='us-west-2')
response = client.create_backup(
    TableName='test',
    BackupName='backup_test'
)
```

I don't want to use 'boto3.client' here.
same I also want to restore my table using boto3.resource()

Comment: Just curious, why not enable point in time recovery on the table. Then you'd have a backup that allows you to restore to any one second in the past 35 days...once you have 35 days worth of backups of course.

Comment: I can ues that, it just I want to know how to backup and restore using wrapper boto3.resource(). To restore point in time backup as well I haven't found way. I mean using resource()

Comment: I have checked dir(boto3.resource()) but no such function for backup and restore

Comment: This repo has a way to do it in python, but some steps call for shelling out to the aws cli -- https://github.com/amitwdh/dynamoDB-backup-restore

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to backup a table using the dynamodb resource for boto3.

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#service-resource